# C# Клонирование переменой интерфейса

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

У меня есть небольшое MVVM приложение. Мне необходимо клонировать ViewModel, чтобы изменения одного не меняло клон этой ViewModel.

**MainViewModel**

```
public void AddHistory(IPageViewModel value)
{
    IPageViewModel clon = (IPageViewModel)value;
    ...
}
```

**IPageViewModel**

```
public interface IPageViewModel
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    string Text { get; set; }
    string id { get; set; }
}
```

Я пытался в `MainViewModel` добавить интерфейс *ICloneable* и его реализовать

```
public void AddHistory(IPageViewModel value)
{
    IPageViewModel clon = (IPageViewModel)value.Clone();
    ...
}

public object Clone()
{
     return MemberwiseClone();
}
```

Но это привело к ошибке:

```
"IPageViewModel" не содержит определения "Clone", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "Clone", принимающий тип "IPageViewModel" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)
```

Реализовать интерфейс *ICloneable*  в  *IPageViewModel* не удалось.

Как правильно клонировать ViewModel?

Comment: Ну так он прямо говорит, что интерфейс `IPageViewModel`, а именно у него вы и пытаетесь вызвать `Clone`, не содержит этого метода. Сначала приведите к `ICloneable` и метод будет доступен

Comment: или унаследуйте `IPageViewModel` от `ICloneable`

Comment: @vitidev можно пример? Я пытался `IPageViewModel` унаследовать от `ICloneable`, но тогда ошибка `"object.MemberwiseClone()" недоступен из-за его уровня защиты`

Comment: `(IPageViewModel)((ICloneable)value).Clone()`

Comment: @vitidev "Unable to cast object of type 'WpfMVVMCore.ViewModels.Page1ViewModel' to type 'System.ICloneable'."

Comment: Ну так реализуйте интерфейс значит. Если вы хотите вызывать метод Clone() значит он должен быть у объекта, у которого вы его хотите вызывать.

Answer (score 0):

Если не хочется ручками писать метод "Клона" данных, можно использовать Json сериализацию и десериализацию. Дженерик метод ниже можно легко использовать.

```
public static T Clone<T>(T source)
{
    var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serialized);
}
```

Comment: Дженерик не положишь в коллекцию, вследствие чего не зарезолвишь из IoC контейнера все вьюмодели как коллекцию. Отсюда выходит тот факт, что смысл использовать дженерик интерфейс для обобщения всех вьюмоделей под один тип вообще отпадает. `JsonConvert` - Newtonsoft.Json устаревшая библиотека, она либо для старых .NET Framework 4.x нужна, либо для Unity, где пока что тот же старый фреймворк. Актуальная библиотека - System.Text.Json. И в дополнение ко всему, если уж на то пошло, то `MemberwiseClone()` использовать эффективнее.

Comment: @aepot я не вижу, чтобы человек, который спрашивал - указывал на наличие необходимости DI контейнера при клоне, вижу очень простую хотелку и очень простую реализацию этого, для чего сложности?

Comment: Этот пост не содержит ответа на вопрос об ошибке `"IPageViewModel" не содержит определения "Clone"`, и так же не объясняет автору, как ему этот дженерик запихнуть в `IPageViewModel`. См. метод `AddHistory`. Если уж считаете, что это хороший вариант, покажите пример, как им пользоваться с учетом окружения, которое продемонстрировал автор. Я предлагаю это сделать именно потому что дженерик здесь неуместен, либо я не вижу удобного способа его применить.

Comment: @aepot очевидно нужно добавить метод в интерфейс `IPageViewModel`, просто не Generic да и все. А в методе параметр не нужен. Можно просто кидать `this`